# Work with database transactions in a functional manner in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, functional-programming

I was looking at this kind of code and wondering, is there anything that can be improved if you approach from *functional programming* perspective?

You don't have to strictly re-implement my example to answer, if you have different example involving Transactions, that would be great.

```
using (var unitOfWork = _uowManager.Begin())
{
    _paymentRepository
       .InsertOrUpdate(payment); // Returns payment instance

    // Being executed to get Payment.Id
    _uowManager
       .SaveChanges();

    _otherRepository
       .OtherMethod(payment.Id); // Could be changed as necessary

    unitOfWork
       .Complete()
}
```

Code above is based on [ASP.NET Boilerplate](http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/) and Entity Framework if it helps.

Comment: In a functional programming language, this sort of thing is typically handled using monads. However, C# isn't primarily an FP language (though it supports it to a degree) and shoehorning monads in just so you can say you're being functional seems unnatural.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert could please you provide some example from functional world. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that creating transactional monad is a great way to handle this. Doesn't matter how much FP is in C#, this creates a lot of benefits:

- single, global, unified way to handle transactions
- don't repeat yourself, write this class once and don't recreate transaction logic n times for each controller function
- you can create this class as interface and mock it in integration tests, for example, to rollback transaction, so your tests don't impact the database state

I use something like this:

```
public class Tx
{     
        public DbConnectionExtra _connection { get; set; } // class which has DbTransaction and DbConnection combined 

        public T UseTx<T>(Func<T> fnToCall)
        {          
            try
            {
                _connection.BeginTransaction();

                var result = fnToCall();

               _connection._transaction.Commit();
               _connection._transaction.Dispose();

                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
               _connection._transaction.Rollback();
                _connection._transaction.Dispose();

                throw;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you're writing that much code to do it, I see why you'd need to wrap, but this is not the proper way to do it. `using (var t = _connection.BeginTransaction()) { var result = fnToCall(); t.Commit(); return result; }` is all you need. No explicit `catch`, no `.Dispose`, no `.Rollback`, all of these are take care of by the `using` and `Transaction.Dispose()`.

Comment: Furthermore, even *that* is too much these days; the recommended approach is to wrap your code in `using (var ts = new TransactionScope()) {... ts.Commit(); }` without any explicit reference to individual transactions. Code that enlists in the transaction scope (which SQL commands will do by default) will become part of the transaction without the need to change that code to be transaction-aware.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that using TransactionScope, which is meant for Distrubuted Transactions, is the right way to go. Do you have any references on that? As far as I could find, this is definetely NOT recommended if you are using EF. About wrapping - it helps, if you have some more logic in catch clause (for example, logging).

Comment: `TransactionScope` versus explicit `SqlTransaction` merits questions of its own (and indeed there are several on SO), so I won't go into that further. It's true that `TransactionScope` is particularly useful for distributed transactions, but that isn't its only use case.

Comment: Extra logic in the `catch` is one thing, but your current code, as written, is simply not correct -- if the transaction encounters a database error, it has already rollbacked, and calling `.Rollback()` again will produce an unhelpful error to that effect. (I am assuming your transactions work much like `SqlTransaction`, of course -- I can't look into `DbConnectionExtra`.) You also definitely don't want to be calling `.Dispose()` explicitly if `using` is an option, and if you do it at all it should be done in a `finally` block.